# Weird error with unique() for pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

Unfortunately I am unable to produce a replicable example, but here's the issue I'm running into - with one dataframe, I am able to loop through the columns and save the count of unique values per column. With another dataframe, which has the same exact columns and data as the first dataframe - the only difference being that the second dataframe is all object dtypes, while the first has some ints and floats - i run into a 'unhashable type: 'dict'' error.

this works:

```
for col in olddf.columns:
    unique = len(olddf[col].unique())
    print(col, unique)
```

i get an unhashable type: 'dict' error with this:

```
for col in orig_results.columns:
    unique = len(orig_results[col].unique())
```

Like I mentioned, unfortunately I'm unable to come up with a sample dataset to replicate. Wondering if anyone by any chance has a general idea of what might be happening? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: For debugging, add a `pring(col)` before your `unique = ...` line so that you know which column is causing the problem. Then you can look into it to see what's the problem. From your error message, it looks like that column contains dictionary objects, which might be causing the error.

Comment: as @TYZ said, use a `try ..except` to print the column name that causes the error.

Comment: @TYZ ah thank you! doing this I was able to figure out it errors out at 'cross_street_1'. however, when i execute the line on this columns alone - len(orig_df['cross_street_1'].unique()), it works...not sure why it wont work in a loop.

Comment: @ChristineJiang could you paste the result of `orig_df['cross_street_1'].unique()`?

Comment: @CavinDsouza yup! 
array([nan, 'DUMONT AVENUE', 'OCEAN PROMENADE', ..., 'STORER AVENUE',
       'ILYSE COURT', 'REDGRAVE AVE'], dtype=object)

Comment: it's basically a list of street addresses. some have numbers in the address and some are just the street

Comment: weird, so the column does not contain any dict objects, so its uncertain as to why the `len()` command fails.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the location column throwing an error, which contains dictionaries as values: {'latitude': '40.7388739110531', 'longitude': '40.738873911'}. since dictionaries are unhashable, we can't get a unique count.